# How to create maps based on conditional panel in R with Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, conditional-statements, user-input

I am trying to create several leaflet maps based on what the user select. I tried to produce a reproducible example.
I have a sf with four shapes (i.e., representing four counties in NC). The user can choose to plot one to four maps based on the choice of the county (made through the "checkboxGroupInput". If the user select one county, I should plot one map representing the county the user selected. If the user selected two counties, two maps should be plotted, etc.

I got several lines of code but I could not connect the user selection to my map. Below you can find what I tried to do. Thanks for any help.

```
library(sf)
 library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(mapedit)
library(DT)
library(viridis)
library(leafem)


nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% head(3)
 
ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Maps"),
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput('MapNumber','Select Maps', choices = c("Ashe", "Alleghany", "Surry"), selected = "Ashe"),
    conditionalPanel(condition="output.MapNum=='1'",
                     fluidRow(
                       column(12,
                              leafletOutput("Map1a")
                       )
                     )
    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition="output.MapNum=='2'",
                     fluidRow(
                       column(6,
                              leafletOutput("Map2a")
                       ),
                       column(6,
                              leafletOutput("Map2b")
                       )
                     )
    ),
    
    conditionalPanel(condition="output.MapNum=='3'",
                     fluidRow(
                       column(6,
                              leafletOutput("Map3a")
                       ),
                       column(6,
                              leafletOutput("Map3b")
                       ),
                       column(6,
                              leafletOutput("Map3c")
                       )
                       
                       )
                     )
    )
    )


server = function(input, output) {
  
  MapInput1a<-reactive({
    req(length(input$MapNumber)==1) 
    input$MapNumber[1] 
  })
  
  MapInput2a<-reactive({
    req(length(input$MapNumber)==2) 
    input$MapNumber[1] 
  })
  
  MapInput2b<-reactive({
    req(length(input$MapNumber)==2) 
    input$MapNumber[2] 
  })  
  
  MapInput3a<-reactive({
    req(length(input$MapNumber)==3) 
    input$MapNumber[1] 
  })  
  
  MapInput3b<-reactive({
    req(length(input$MapNumber)==3) 
    input$MapNumber[2] 
  })  
  
  MapInput3c<-reactive({
    req(length(input$MapNumber)==3) 
    input$MapNumber[3] 
  })  
  
  
  output$Map1a<-renderLeaflet({leaflet()%>% addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB", group = "CartoDB") %>%
    addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
    addFeatures("?")})# do not know how to plot the feature correctly, and I do not know how to do for output$Map2a, 
 # output$Map2b, etc.
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I would use a rather different approach to get the job done. Instead of creatign that many conditional panels, I would write a function that creates a collection of columns depending on the number of counties selected.

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)


nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% head(3)

# This function returns a collection of leaflet plots based on county names
maps_ui <-function(counties, shapefiles) {

  n_counties <- length(counties)
  colum_with <- 12 / n_counties

  maps <- purrr::map(
    counties,
    ~shiny::column(
      width = colum_with,
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%
        addProviderTiles("CartoDB", group = "CartoDB") %>%
        addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
        addPolygons(data = nc[nc$NAME == .x, ]) %>%
        addLegend(
          position = 'bottomright', 
          colors = c("#5663E2", "#F4BC35", "#E45F71"), 
          labels = c ("1", "2", "3"), 
          opacity = 0.5, title = .x )
    )
      )
  )

  return(maps)

}


# The app

ui = fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput('counties', 'Select Maps', choices = c("Ashe", "Alleghany", "Surry"), selected = "Ashe"),
  fluidRow(uiOutput('maps'))
)


server = function(input, output) {

  output$maps <- renderUI({
    maps_ui(input$counties, nc)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, that is pretty efficient, I have not though about it.

Comment: Do you know how to set up the legend name for each map with the corresponding county name. So far I added: addLegend(
          position = 'bottomright',
          colors = c("#5663E2", "#F4BC35", "#E45F71"),
          labels = c ("1", "2", "3"), opacity = 0.5,
          title =paste(nc$NAME)
        )                                                                                  but all the counties name are written for each map (e.g., Ashe, Allgehany, Surry)

Comment: You can take a look at the documentation. http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/

Comment: I typed too fast earlier (I added my lines of code). I looked at this documentation but in my case, I do not understand how to adapt the legend based on the shiny select input

Comment: Lets create a chat room.

Comment: sure thing, I will try to create one